# Flutter display package:image/image.dart:Image in UI Widget

Tags: flutter, image, dart, type-conversion

We can work on images **in Flutter** using `import 'package:image/image.dart' as ToolsImage;` package to **scale** them with `ToolsImage.copyResize()` and manipulate individual pixels with `ToolsImage.Image.getPixel(x,y)`

To display image from memory bytes (`ByteData`/`Uint8List`/`List<int>`) we can use `MemoryImage`:

```
Container(child: Image(image: MemoryImage(image.data.buffer.asUint8List())))
```

I'm getting an exception:

`Exception: Invalid image data`

whichever List I use. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remember **to add HEADER to image bytes** after format conversions!

```
ByteData imageByteData = await rootBundle.load('res/images/basic/dizzy-face.png');
List<int> values = imageByteData.buffer.asUint8List();
ToolsImage.Image? photo = ToolsImage.decodeImage(values);
photo = ToolsImage.copyResize(photo!, height: 32, width: 32);
```

removes header information (pixel-by-pixel manipulation removes header info).

Use:

```
List<int>? imageWithHeader = ToolsImage.encodeNamedImage(TEST_IMAGE, ".bmp");
```

and then:

```
Container(child: Image(image: MemoryImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageWithHeader))))
```

Last line enables us to convert `package:image/image.dart` to `package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart` (UI Image Widget)