# How can I programmatically create an ImgDetails in Dart?

Tags: image, dart

I want to write Dart tests that create images programmatically, e.g. with all pixels initially set to blue and then changing some of them to red.  There is no image file.  I do not want to display the image.  I just want to create an ImgDetails object with specific pixel patterns and pass it to some Dart function I am trying to test.

I can't find any examples like this; I see mainly Dart apps that load image file assets using ImageStreams, ImageProviders, etc. and display them.  Is there some class that will allow me to bang on a 2D array of pixels and then get an ImgDetails object for it?

Comment: You might try [ui.decodeImageFromPixels()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/decodeImageFromPixels.html): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68453359/421195

Comment: @paulsm4 That looks promising; thanks!